# Modelo en capas de una Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

He desarrollado una Web Api con la ayuda del Framework Asp.Net Web Api y de Entity Framework. Mi duda no es de código sino mas bien un detalle conceptual que espero me puedan ayudar.

Basado en el modelo de desarrollo de capas (Base de datos, Acceso a Datos, Negocio, Presentación) es fácil decir que:

La capa de acceso a datos está compuesta por las clases autogeneradas por el ORM Entity Framework
La capa de negocio o lógica de negocio se forma de las N clases (`ApiController`) que permiten procesar la información que arriba de los clientes, estas clases están escritas en lenguaje C#.

```
[HttpGet]
            [Route("api/cliente/negocio")]
            public IHttpActionResult ClientesNegocio(int id)
            {
                List<clientes_x_negocios> clientesNegocio = db.clientes_x_negocios.Include("clientes").Where(i => i.idNegocio == id && i.estado == true).ToList();
                return (Ok(r.ok(clientesNegocio.Select(i => i.clientes).ToList())));
            }
```

Pero que pasa con la capa de presentación? 
Esta compuesta por los archivos de configuración que permiten ¨construir una interface¨ para presentar los distintos métodos escritos??

Alguien podría guiarme con esta duda, muchas gracias

Comment: La capa de presentación DEBERÍA tener los archivos con los que vas a construir la interfaz gráfica donde el usuario final va a interactuar con tu sistema (html, css, script). Ten en cuenta que los controladores funcionan como **puente** entra la interfaz gráfica y la capa de interacción con la BD

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, pero como explique al inicio, desarrolle una web API, es decir no tengo vistas que interactuan con el cliente final, sino que tengo una aplicación móvil que consume la web API a través de peticiones Http y es la aplicación móvil quien interatua con el cliente

Comment: En ese caso no necesitarías capa de presentación. No es obligación tenerla si lo que quieres es sólo exponer los métodos.